# How to Create and Sort an Array of Dictionaries of Floats

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I have a custom object that contains some properties that are floats (as well as others that are strings, dates etc.). Discarding the non-float properties, I would like to filter out non-zero properties, sort them by size and display them. As a swift newbie, however, I'm having trouble.

My object looks like this:

```
@objc public class MyTone: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var date: Date = Date()
    var val1: Float = 0
    var val2: Float = 0
    var val3: Float = 0
//...
    var val10: Float = 0;
}
```

My code so far based on what I've found on Google is:

```
let propArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = [
            ["prop": "val1" as AnyObject,
             "value": 0.3 as AnyObject],
            ["prop":  "val2" as AnyObject,
             "value": 0.2 as AnyObject],
            ["prop": "val3" as AnyObject,
             "value": 0.4 as AnyObject]
        ]

   let sortedArray = propArray.sort { (first, second,third) in
            return first["value"]?.floatValue < second["value"]?.floatValue< third["value"]?.floatValue
        }
```

Fixit asked me to insert the anyObject code but I am getting error 'Any Object is Not Subtype of NSNumber'.  In addition, I don't really understand what first, second and so forth mean... Are these terms that the compiler understands?  It seems there might be a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Also, why not just make an array of your object? `[MyTone]`?

Comment: `AnyObject` is nonsense. Value types like `String`,  `Float` and `Date` are `Any`. The array is `[[String:Any]]`. This avoids the ugly as `AnyObject` bridge casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using collection method `sorted` because you cannot use mutating member on immutable value.

Secondly there is no third param of sort function cloure only (first, second). See doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted)

Thirdly for `first["value"]?.floatValue` you must provide default value e.g '0' because it's optional.

```
let sortedArray = propArray.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return first["value"]?.floatValue ?? 0 < second["value"]?.floatValue ?? 0
}
```

Comment: `propArray` is a `let`

Comment: Following several Fixit suggestions , I got it to work by making change suggested by @vadian and as follows: let sortedArray = propArray.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
            return (first["value"] as AnyObject).floatValue ?? 0 < (second["value"] as AnyObject).floatValue ?? 0
        }

Comment: Question Bilal: What do first and second designate?  I gather these are some sort of recognized terms for sorting?  Also, anyone who thinks this is a useful question, please upvote. The downvoting for no reason is a form of bullying.

Comment: @Carpsen90 not necessarily because it's `Trailing closure syntax`

Comment: @user1904273 first and second are params of closure. And closure is passed to `sorted by` method.

Comment: Ok.  I guess first > second is what $0 > $1  refer to?

Comment: Yes thats right. like this `let sortedArray = propArray.sorted { $0["value"]?.floatValue ?? 0 < $1["value"]?.floatValue ?? 0 }`

Comment: Stop using `AnyObject` and the ObjC runtime. It's `let sortedArray = propArray.sorted { ($0["value"] as? Float ?? 0.0) < $1["value"] as? Float ?? 0.0 }`